# Build PIC development board on bread board

Tags: breadboard, programmer, board, development

I have PIC24FJ128GA202 IC only. Since development boards cost too much, I would like to build a development board  on a bread board and try some sample programs on it.

Like the image below:

[image]

Is it possible to build it this way? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes.  If you post a circuit diagram, we can tell you if it's correct

Comment: Will is have the exact same performance? No. Such is the difference between bread-boards and PCBs. Will it work for small experiments and learning? Absolutely!

Comment: Just learning purpose only.

Comment: Or, design a PCB and get a few made. They are available very cheaply from Chinese suppliers. Performance will be a lot better and it will be more reliable.

Comment: If you can, build a very simple dev board containing everything to run the IC (oscillator, buffering caps, ...). Equip it with pin headers so you can just plug into your bread board. This way, you save lots of space on the bread board, you can concentrate on the actual task, and don't have to struggle with the set-up of the IC each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible if your PIC part is in a SPDIP package. If you have parts in the SOIC or SSOP package then it would not be possible to mount the parts on a standard breadboard.

Be aware that there can be issues with proto boards that can make the learning experience a painful one. The main issues that you could see include:

1. Intermittent connections.
2. Not compatible for high frequency operation.
3. Poor power and ground distribution and bypassing.
4. Capacitive coupling between adjacent circuit nodes.
5. Shorts between component leads that are inserted without cutting them.